# How can I restrict a Service context menu item to appear only when certain text is selected?

Tags: automator, services, contextual-menu

I am trying to figure out a way to have a Service show up in a context menu when text is selected, but if and only if that selected text is a URL.

The Automator Service in question will take the selected text and then save it to my "Reading List."

Safari has *"Add To Reading List"* in its default context menu. But I exclusively use Google Chrome on my Macbook Pro. So, what I've been doing for nearly 2 years now is I manually copy the URL to  the clipboard, open Safari, and add the URL to my "Reading List" manually.

Is there a way to restrain a context menu item for a Service so that this context menu item only appears if the selected text begins with "http" (for example), so that I don't have one more unnecessary item cluttering my context menu?

Comment: If you exclusively use Google Chrome, then why have you been adding URLs to the Reading List in Safari?

Comment: For iOS devices. I use Safari on iOS devices.

Comment: To whomever down-voted this question, care to offer an explanation as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.

The following is automatically presented at the top of the Automator window when a Service is created:

[image]